# How to make a table row clickable in struts 1.x

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

Iam new to struts. My question is "How to make a table row  clickable and get the index in the action class

Currently i have

```
<logic:iterate id="LIST" name="LIST" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <bean:write name="LIST" property="details"/></td>
                            <td> <bean:write name="LIST" property="name"/></td>
                            <td> <bean:write name="LIST" property="id"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</logic:iterate>
```

**Note: I dont want to use java statements within jsp**

Comment: How do you mean clickable? Your specifications are too sparse.

Comment: I want to make each of these row clickable. there is no complexity. I need to interact with action class on that click thats it.